# Would like to displayonly last 4 digits on phone number using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to show last 4 digits phone number on page which i am going to get from API.
Can you please help me? format should be like (XXX)XXX-1234

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific.You can use a pipe for formatting it in desired way.

Answer (score 0):

While your question isn't very specific, you might consider using this: [Angular 
SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

That way you can get the last 4 digits of the phone number using string indices.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a javascript answer, but you could create an expression, then use it in your HTML.

```
$scope.formatPhone = function(phoneNumber) {
    if(phoneNumber) {
        return '(XXX)XXX-' + phoneNumber.substr(phoneNumber.length - 4);
    }
    return '';
}
```